# What are support measures offered by German universities to international students which are often met with low demand?

Tags: germany

> There is a wide range of support services for international students at German higher
> education institutions, especially in the introductory phase of studies, but also over
> the course of the study programmes. However, these are often only used by a relatively
> small proportion of international students, and their willingness to participate decreases
> over time. Consideration should therefore be given to how international students can
> be motivated more effectively to make greater use of the existing support services or
> how their benefits can be better explained to them. This applies especially to language
> courses, not only at the beginning of the study program, but throughout the entire course of study. This could, for example, prevent international students from failing to
> write their final thesis due to language problems
>
> [Source DAAD study](https://static.daad.de/media/daad_de/pdfs_nicht_barrierefrei/der-daad/was-wir-tun/daad_sesaba_abschlussbericht.pdf)

Could someone mention examples of these wide range of support services? I am someone interested in studying in Germany, and till date I have not heard of any support services as such till date.